# Pivot longer with mutliple data points in a single column

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a data frame containing a varying number of data points in the same column:

```r
library(tidyverse)


df <- tribble(~id,  ~data,
              "A", "a;b;c",
              "B",   "e;f")
```

I want to obtain one row per data point, separating the content of column `data` and distributing it on rows. This code gives the expected result, but is clumsy:

```r
df %>%
  separate(data,
           into = paste0("dat_",1:5),
           sep = ";",
           fill = "right") %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with("dat_"),
               names_to = "data_number",
               names_pattern = "dat_(\\d+)") %>%
  filter(!is.na(value))

#> # A tibble: 5 x 3
#>   id    data_number value
#>   <chr> <chr>       <chr>
#> 1 A     1           a    
#> 2 A     2           b    
#> 3 A     3           c    
#> 4 B     1           e    
#> 5 B     2           f
```

Tidyverse solutions preferred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
df %>% 
      separate_rows(data) %>%
      mutate(data_number = rowid(id), .before = 2)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  id    data_number data 
  <chr>       <int> <chr>
1 A               1 a    
2 A               2 b    
3 A               3 c    
4 B               1 e    
5 B               2 f
```

Comment: That's great! If we wish to stay pure tidyverse, we can also create data_number using `group_by(id) %>% mutate(data_number = row_number())`.

Comment: @Alexlok that is true, i was thinking to make it compact as you were asking for compactness.

Comment: I am mentioning it for completeness (I will accept your answer as soon as possible with or without it). The "clumsiness" mentioned in the question was about having to guess the number of values, not so much compactness.

Comment: @Alexlok yes, I understand.  I think the `group_by` row_number is great as well, but only issue I have is with the group attribute unless we do `ungroup`.  In some situations, people forget about it and get some strange thinks

Answer (score 2):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
    separate_rows(data)
```

output:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  id    data 
  <chr> <chr>
1 A     a    
2 A     b    
3 A     c    
4 B     e    
5 B     f
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `str_split` and `unnest` -

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(data = str_split(data, ';'), 
         data_number = map(data, seq_along)) %>%
  unnest(c(data, data_number))

#  id    data  data_number
#  <chr> <chr>       <int>
#1 A     a               1
#2 A     b               2
#3 A     c               3
#4 B     e               1
#5 B     f               2
```